# Adding on values to a key based on different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add on values to a key after making a dictionary.

This is what I have so far:

```
movie_list = "movies.txt"  # using a file that contains this order on first line: Title, year, genre, director, actor 
in_file = open(movie_list, 'r')
in_file.readline()

def list_maker(in_file):
    movie1 = str(input("Enter in a movie: "))
    movie2 = str(input("Enter in another movie: "))

    d = {}
    for line in in_file:  
        l = line.split(",")
        title_year = (l[0], l[1]) # only then making the tuple ('Title', 'year')
        for i in range(4, len(l)):
            d = {title_year: l[i]} 

        if movie1 or movie2 == l[0]:
            print(d.values())
```

The output I get it:

```
Enter in a movie: 13 B
Enter in another movie: 1920
{('13 B', '(2009)'): 'R. Madhavan'}
{('13 B', '(2009)'): 'Neetu Chandra'}
{('13 B', '(2009)'): 'Poonam Dhillon\n'}
{('1920', '(2008)'): 'Rajneesh Duggal'}
{('1920', '(2008)'): 'Adah Sharma'}
{('1920', '(2008)'): 'Anjori Alagh\n'}
{('1942 A Love Story', '(1994)'): 'Anil Kapoor'}
{('1942 A Love Story', '(1994)'): 'Manisha Koirala'}
{('1942 A Love Story', '(1994)'): 'Jackie Shroff\n'}
.... so on and so forth. I get the whole list of movies.
```

How would I go about doing so if I wanted to enter in those two movies (any 2 movies as a union of the values to the key (movie1, movie2) )?

Example:

```
{('13 B', '(2009)'): 'R. Madhavan', 'Neetu Chandra', 'Poonam Dhillon'}
{('1920', '(2008)'): 'Rajneesh Duggal', 'Adah Sharma', 'Anjori Alagh'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if the output isn't completely what you want, but here's how you should do it:

```
d = {}
for line in in_file:  
    l = line.split(",")
    title_year = (l[0], l[1])
    people = []
    for i in range(4, len(l)):
        people.append(l[i]) # we append items to the list...
    d = {title_year: people} # ...and then make the dict so that the list is in it. 

    if movie1 or movie2 == l[0]:
        print(d.values())
```

Basically, what we are doing here is that we are making a list, and then setting the list to a key inside of the dict.